# OptionMenu variable not getting assigned a value in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to assign a string value to the variable in OptionMenu in tkinter, and this is not working. The menu displays just fine and I am able to select an option with the mouse. Should be simple enough, so I must be missing something. It seems to me that the main_page() function is running once and so no variable assignment is made. I could do a root.after(100, lambda: self.main_page()), but that will constantly redraw the whole page which is not good. Help please?

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime as dt
import time

class Main:
    def __init__(self,master):
        # create splash screen
        self.splash = Canvas(master, bg='lightgreen')
        self.splash.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        ...
        self.splash.bind("<Key>",self.splash_key)
        self.splash.focus_set()

    def datetime_fetch(self):
        # display current date and time
        ...

    def main_page(self):
        # main page display
        self.main_frame = Frame(root, bg="white")
        self.main_frame.pack(fill="both")
        file_menu_var = StringVar()
        menu_select = OptionMenu(self.main_frame, file_menu_var, "New", "Open", "Save", "Save as", "Close", "Quit")
        menu_select.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.datetime_fetch()
        if file_menu_var.get() == 'New':
            print(file_menu_var.get())         

    def splash_key(self,event):
        self.splash.destroy()
        self.main_page()

root = Tk()
root.wm_title('Budgeteer')
root.attributes('-zoomed',True)
root.configure(background="lightblue")
app = Main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two problems in your code. For one, `file_menu_var` is a local variable. For another, you're calling `file_menu_var.get()` about a millisecond after creating the widget, far before the user has a chance to change anything.

You need to keep a persistent reference to the variable, and you need to wait to call the `file_menu_var.get()` until after the user has had a chance to interact with the menu. This is typically done by placing a trace on the associated variable.